# C literals and overflow

Tags: c, integer

On my machine, where an `int` is 32 bits, the following code :

```
int64_t m = (int64_t) 1 << 60;
int64_t n = (int64_t) 2048 * 2048 * 2048;
```

gives the mathematically expected results of 2^60 and 2^33 even though the standard seems to say that 1 and 2048 should be treaded as "int".

Should I consider that result as luck, or does the C99 standard guarantees that I don't get overflow?

Comment: FWIW: C does not define _literal_.  Instead C calls `2048` a _constant_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting has precedence on many other operations, you can see the order here [http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~wkliao/op-prec.htm](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/%7Ewkliao/op-prec.htm)

So you are actually working with int64_t all the time (as the name says, it's  a signed integer with 64 bits) and that's why you don't overflow.